# Create a new variable based on multiple complex conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Below is a reproducible example. This is based on how different countries vote at the United Nations General Assembly.

Say we have three columns titled "VoteID", "Country", and "Vote" :

```
VoteID <- c("Vote1","Vote1","Vote1",
            "Vote2","Vote2","Vote2")
Country <- c("CountryA", "CountryB", "CountryC", 
             "CountryA", "CountryB", "CountryC")
Vote <- c("Yes", "Yes", "No",
          "No", "No", "Yes")

df <- data.frame(VoteID, Country, Vote)

df
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
   VoteID   Country      Vote
   Vote1    CountryA     Yes
   Vote1    CountryB     Yes
   Vote1    CountryC     No
   Vote2    CountryA     No
   Vote2    CountryB     No
   Vote2    CountryC     Yes
```

I would like to create a new variable called `CountryCVote` which represents how Country C voted, **but for each vote id**.

That is, for each vote id, there should be a 'Vote' column that represents how each country voted, and a "CountryCVote" column that represents how CountryC voted for that Vote ID. The resulting dataframe with the new variable should look like this:

```
  VoteID   Country     Vote   CountryCVote
  Vote1    CountryA    Yes    No
  Vote1    CountryB    Yes    No 
  Vote1    CountryC    No     No
  Vote2    CountryA    No     Yes
  Vote2    CountryB    No     Yes
  Vote2    CountryC    Yes    Yes
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(VoteID) %>%
  mutate(key = ifelse(any(Vote =="Yes" & Country == "CountryC"), "Yes", "No"))

  VoteID Country  Vote  key  
  <chr>  <chr>    <chr> <chr>
1 Vote1  CountryA Yes   No   
2 Vote1  CountryB Yes   No   
3 Vote1  CountryC No    No   
4 Vote2  CountryA No    Yes  
5 Vote2  CountryB No    Yes  
6 Vote2  CountryC Yes   Yes
```

Comment: This worked. My 'vote' column has multiple categories but I was able to follow the logic. Was not aware of the any() function that lets you do this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
data.table::setDT(df)[
  df[Country=="CountryC",.(VoteID, CountryCVote=Vote)],
  on=.(VoteID)]
```

Output:

```
   VoteID  Country Vote CountryCVote
1:  Vote1 CountryA  Yes           No
2:  Vote1 CountryB  Yes           No
3:  Vote1 CountryC   No           No
4:  Vote2 CountryA   No          Yes
5:  Vote2 CountryB   No          Yes
6:  Vote2 CountryC  Yes          Yes
```